# Union (or) type in sql

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I want a column in my table to be able to take one of two data types. Specifically I want it to take either a dictionary or a string.

If the column is called column1 then I would like the type in the table would look something like

column1 JSONB or TEXT

Is this possible in SQL? Also, I know it is oftentimes considered bad practice to put dictionaries in tables.

Comment: Why not just store the text as JSON?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Serialize your data to something your database engine can handle and then store that. It sounds to me like you want an object database and not a relational database.

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `jsonb`. Assuming you are Postgres you can store a simple value in a `jsonb` column: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=10a0aa4273e9ee8ed5391652d04f56b8